# Edit Mode inside Angular ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a requirement to implement an editable list for a project I am working on. When you click on an item it changes to an edit state that has a bunch of options related to the item you clicked on. Our UX wants the items to be edited in-line but I am not sure of the best way to do this in angular and would like to know which way is better.

**Example 1 Template**

```
<div class="person" ng-repeat="person in people" ng-click="editing=!editing">
    <div class="details-view" ng-hide="editing" ng-bind="person.name"></div>
    <div class="edit-view" ng-show="editing">
      <input type="text" /> <button type="button">Save</button> <a>Cancel</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Example 1 Controller**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.people = [
    {name: 'Joe', age:23},
    {name: 'Jim', age:32},
    {name: 'Jill', age:13}
  ]
});
```

The first way ([example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ry0sdEwIe7D19c5ssJjP?p=preview)) is to have an ng-repeat and inside of each ng-repeat item create an edit mode that is specific to the ng-repeat item. This works great but I don't want to leave edit mode until I have a successful response from the server and I don't understand how to handle that using this method.

**Example 2 Template**

```
<div class="person" ng-repeat="person in people" ng-click="toggleEditing(person)">
    <div class="details-view" ng-hide="person.editing" ng-bind="person.name"></div>
    <div class="edit-view" ng-show="person.editing">
      <input type="text" /> <button type="button">Save</button> <a>Cancel</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Example 2 Controller**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.people = [
    {name: 'Joe', age:23},
    {name: 'Jim', age:32},
    {name: 'Jill', age:13}
  ];

  $scope.toggleEditing = function(person) {
    person.editing = !person.editing;
  };
});
```

The second way ([example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/gVYA0A69ZBJ4pwtH14aU)) I thought of is to duck punch the view state onto the object. I don't like this way because I don't want to modify the object handed to me by the ng-repeat.This method does allow me to handle the successful save that the first way above doesn't.

Are there any better options?

Comment: Your examples are empty plunkers

Comment: Grrr, must have not saved. I'll redo the examples

Comment: Looks like they are having issues right now so I just added the code to my question.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to clutter the object with the view state, you can save the view state in an different object.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.editedItems = {};

  $scope.people = [
    {name: 'Joe', age:23},
    {name: 'Jim', age:32},
    {name: 'Jill', age:13}
  ];

  $scope.toggleEditing = function(person) {
    $scope.editedItems[person.name] = 
    !$scope.editedItems[person.name] || true;
  };
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="person" ng-repeat="person in people" ng-click="toggleEditing(person)">
            <div class="details-view" ng-hide="editedItems[person.name]" ng-bind="person.name"></div>
            <div class="edit-view" ng-show="editedItems[person.name]">
                <input type="text" /> <button type="button">Save</button> <a>Cancel</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [ng-grid](http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/) instead of ng-repeat? They have a good edit in-line model and it seems to have better UX than the ng-hide/ng-show options.